# How can I acces to getSupportFragmentManager in external java listener

Tags: java, android, android-context

I have to set the listener for a `NavigationView` in my main class. But the main, will containt a lot of stuff, and I want to have it the most "separated" possible.

So I will do listeners in their own java files, to something like:

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationListener());
```

The problem comes, that I have to call `getSupportFragmentManager` , but is not accesible, so, I suppose that I need to do something like: `context.getSupportFragmentManager` to make ir "work".

But I don't know how to get the context.

How can I get it?

ListenerClass:

```
public class NavigationListener implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        boolean fragmentTransaction = false;
        String TAG = "NavigationViewListener";
        Logger.init(TAG);
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_home:
                fragment = new FragmentHome();
                fragmentTransaction = true;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_map:
                fragment = new FragmentMap();
                fragmentTransaction = true;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_log_out:
                Logger.d("Pulsada opnción de LogOut");
                break;
        }

        if(fragmentTransaction){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.main_content, fragment)
                    .commit();

            item.setChecked(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(item.getTitle());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just pass the instance of your `FragmentActivity` to `NavigationListener` as a constructor param:

```
public class NavigationListener implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    FragmentActivity activity;        

    public NavigationListener(FragmentActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // ...

        if(fragmentTransaction){
            activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_content, fragment)
                .commit();

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

From your `FragmentActivity`:

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationListener(this));
```